# keep each line containing x only if column y is the first containing x. remove the rest containing x

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

I'm trying to reduce a results file that contains multiple results for sometimes the same query and I only want the top result from each query.

Using bash and bash tools like awk, sed, etc. I would like to take a CSV or TSV, and for each line, look at stringX in columnY (in this case column 4), keep this line and remove all other lines that contain value x before moving onto the next line.

So far I have a sed command that can remove all but the first instance of stringX

`sed '1!{/stringX/d}'`

I would like to use awk to create a variable of the stringX from the columnY to then pass on to sed to do its thing (or if there is another more efficient way). I would like to do as much of this efficiently as possible, so trying to iterate through the file as little as possible would be good.

Example of input:

```
4.9e-110,360.1,25.4,SL4.0ch08
3.5e-104,357.2,26.6,CM026542.1
1.8e-102,352.6,23.2,SL4.0ch08
4e-100,353.7,21.8,HG975447.1
3e-79,324.2,21.7,CM026542.1
5.1e-86,300.5,21.6,CP047564.1
1.1e-84,296.2,22.2,CP055241.1
1.1e-79,279.6,19.5,HG975447.1
3e-67,238.5,24.8,CP055241.1
1.6e-64,229.4,28.9,CP047564.1
1.6e-62,222.8,25.0,CP047564.1
5.1e-61,217.9,30.5,CM026542.1
etc...
```

Example of desired output:

```
4.9e-110,360.1,25.4,SL4.0ch08
3.5e-104,357.2,26.6,CM026542.1
4e-100,353.7,21.8,HG975447.1
5.1e-86,300.5,21.6,CP047564.1
1.1e-84,296.2,22.2,CP055241.1
```

So far this is where I'm at:

```
results=$(ls results/*.txt)
for iB in $results
do
        uniqList=$(awk -F, '{print $4}' "$iB" | sort -u)
        for iC in $uniqList
        do
                sed -i '1!{/'"$iC"'/d}' "$iB"
        done
done
```

The idea here is that I use awk to print column 4 to a list, sort it and get rid of any duplicates. Then with that list, run it through sed (Am I using single and double quotes properly here?). This unfortunately gives me this result, which is only the top line of the file:

```
4.9e-110,360.1,25.4,SL4.0ch08
```

I'm doing something wrong, but am at a loss. Any help, greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
So, I went this route, which is nice and simple and seems to be working for me:

```
awk -F, '!x[$4]++'
```

A far as I can tell, awk here is checking the 4th column (field), if it's not seen it before, then it's printing the whole line and moving on, if it has seen it before, it won't print it and move on.

Comment: Your self created solution is pithy and looks like it addresses the problem.  I suggest you add it as an answer and mark it the accepted solution.

Comment: @Slartibartfast Thanks. Have added it as an answer. I now need to wait 2 days to mark it as accepted it seems.

Answer (score 1):

So, I went this route, which is nice and simple and seems to be working for me:

```
awk -F, '!x[$4]++'
```

A far as I can tell, awk here is checking the 4th column (field), if it's not seen it before, then it's printing the whole line and moving on, if it has seen it before, it won't print it and move on.

Comment: The script is creating a hash table named x, and looking within it to see if there is an entry  matching the 4th element of the current line.  The clever part:  First, awk gets that value and tests to see if it is "not" (the exclamation point) "true" (equal to zero or non-existent), which means it evaluates to true the first time you look it up.  Immediately thereafter, the value is incremented (the double-plus placed after means: after evaluating this, add one to it), so the next time you look it up, it exists and is nonzero and the test fails every other time (and so doesn't print)